# Ocultar o mostrar botones segun el cargo

Tags: php

Inicio sesion con el usuario en cuestion... traspaso la $_SESSION hacia la vista del home y en ella tomo esta sesion para buscar informacion del usuario logeado. La funcion me retorna en string la informacion requerida.

```
include("../Modelos/ValidarConsultas.php");
session_start();
$sesion=$_SESSION['usur']['rutusur'];
$cargo = getcargo($sesion);
$rol = getrol($sesion);

VAR_dump($cargo);
var_dump($rol);
if($sesion==null || $sesion=""){
    header("location:../index.php");
    die();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CONTRUNITY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css">

    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.php">
            <img src="../img/LogoContrunity.png" alt="CONTRUNITY" style="width:80px;" class="rounded-pill"> 
            </a>
        </div>
      <div class="nav justify-content-end">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                Opciones
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lista insumos</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lista empleados</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="../Controladores/CerrarSesion.php">Cerrar sesion</a>
            </li>
           
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron ">
          <h1 class="display-4" style="font-family: 'Archivo Black';"> BIENVENIDO</h1>
          <hr class="my-4">
          
        </div> 
      </div>
    
      <div class="container">
      
        <div class="row">
        <?php if($cargo=='Jefedeobra' || $rol=='1') {?>
          <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
            <a href="ListaInsumos.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
              <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
                <h5>Buscar Insumo</h5>
                <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/520925/search-sort.svg" style="width:60px;">
              </div>         
            </a>
          </div>
          <?php }else if ($cargo=='RRHH' || $rol=='1') {?>
          <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: left;">
            <a href="ListaEmpleados.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
              <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
                <h5>Buscar Empleado</h5>
                <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/520925/search-sort.svg" style="width:60px;">
              </div>         
            </a>
          </div>
          <?php }else if($cargo=="Jefedeobra" || $rol="1" ){ ?>
          <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
            <a href="RegistroInsumos.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
              <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
                <h5>Registro Insumo</h5>
                <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/509701/add-to-cart.svg" style="width:60px;">
              </div>         
            </a>
          </div>
          <?php }else if($cargo=="RRHH" || $rol="1"){ ?>
          <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: left;">
            <a href="RegistroPersonas.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
              <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
                <h5>Registro Empleado</h5>
                <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/510317/user-plus.svg" style="width:60px;">
              </div>         
            </a>
          </div>
          <?php }else if($cargo=="Capataz" || $cargo=="Obrero" || $rol="1" ){ ?>
          <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: right;">
            <a href="SolicitudInsumos.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
              <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
                <h5>Solicitar Insumos</h5>
                <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/6094/insert-file.svg" style="width:60px;">
              </div>         
            </a>
          </div>
          <?php }else if($cargo=="Jefedeobra" || $rol="1" ){ ?>
          <div class="col-sm-6" style="text-align: left;">
            <a href="ListaSolicitudes.php" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="btn_cur" style="margin: 10px; ">   
              <div class="" style="width: 250px;">
                <h5>Lista Solicitudes</h5>
                <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/522164/list.svg" style="width:60px;">
              </div>         
            </a>
          </div>
          <?php }else{
            header("location:../index.php");
          } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </section>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Utilizo el vardump parar mostrar los datos y estos son.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

string(7) "Capataz" string(1) "1"

Y la vista solo pasa por el primer if y me muestra ese boton

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y deberia quedar de la siguiente manera ya que el rol es 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las variables las toma y las guarda, pero al momento de comparar no ejecuta de manera correcta... talvez estoy utilizando mal los operadores logicos.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev lo hice y no me rersulto